# When to use control-group with Twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have searched the internet, but cannot find a definition in what instances I would want to use the "control-group" class in twitter-bootstrap...

Can someone please inform me of when this class would need to be used?

Comment: When you use a horizontal form in Bootstrap 2 you wrap labels and controls in .control-group. For more info: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#forms (under Horizontal form).

Comment: How about if you're using Bootstrap 3?

Comment: In bootstrap 3 you use .form-group instead of .control-group. See: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Comment: Ok, thanks so much.. That clears things up...

Comment: You're welcome. You can find a full list of class changes here: http://getbootstrap.com/migration/#classes

Answer (score 3):

**Bootstrap 2**

You can use .control-group to wrap labels and controls in a horizontal form.

See: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#forms

**Bootstrap 3**

In bootstrap 3 you use .form-group (instead of .control-group) to wrap labels and controls.

See: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

**Migration**

For a full list of class changes (from 2.x to 3.x) you can check the migration guide.

See: http://getbootstrap.com/migration/#classes